# btnDelete throws else statement delete Method using DAO

Tags: java, android, android-room, dao

I keep getting an else statement whenever I press btnDelete.

```
`// SQLITE_ROOM_DAO interface
@Delete
int delete(Users user);

// UserRepo class
public int delete(Users user) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    int result = new DeleteUserAsyncTask(sqlite_room_dao).execute(user).get();
    return result;
}

private static class DeleteUserAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Users, Void, Integer> {
    private SQLITE_ROOM_DAO sqlite_room_dao;

    private DeleteUserAsyncTask(SQLITE_ROOM_DAO sqlite_room_dao) {
        this.sqlite_room_dao = sqlite_room_dao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Users... users) {

        return sqlite_room_dao.delete(users[0]);
    }
}

// UserViewModel class
public int delete(Users users) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    logger.LogError(TAG, "Delete", logger.jsonConverter(users));
    return userRepo.delete(users);
}

//MainActivity
btnDelete.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    UserViewModel userViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserViewModel.class);
    Users user = new Users(0, "kylomiguel", "44", "44");

    try {
        int result = userViewModel.delete(user);
        if (result > 0) {
            logger.LogError(tag, "Delete", "success");
        } else {
            logger.LogError(tag, "Delete", "failed");
        }
    } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});`
```

I tried to remove try catch but I'm receiving error: Unhandled exceptions: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException, java.lang.InterruptedException

What or where is my bug come from
TYIA.

Comment: `AsyncTask` is deprecated. You'd consider executors instead. The `delete` method returns synchronously, so it doesn't return the actual needed result; You need a sort of listener instead

Comment: Thanks for the tip I found the solution and implemented the executors instead of Async using this

public int delete(Users user) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        Callable<Integer> deleteCallable = new Callable<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call() throws Exception {
                return sqlite_room_dao.delete(user.getUsername());
            }
        };
        Future<Integer> future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(deleteCallable);
        return future.get();
    }